# Azure Virtual Machine Connecting to SQL Server through Active Directory user

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I am a newbie in Azure and have complex system .I have following condition.

1. Virtual Machine(vm1) where I have have installed ADDS(Active Directory Domain Service)
2. I have created few user in vm1
3. I have Created New SQL server Virtual Machine(vm2) where SQL 2015 is running and have database on it.
4. I have Created another Virtual Machine (vm3) where i need to install my application.
5. I have added the Domain name and configure DNS on vm2 and vm3 with respect to vm1.
6. In vm2, when i try to give the permission to the database for user from vm1, I can do it.
7. Now , when i try to run the application with respective user from vm1 from vm3 , I cannot talk with the database .

I have followed up many links but still not found solution.

Comment: did you opened ports in firewall ?

Comment: yes I opened only one port and tried to connect through that port

Comment: your best bet would be to use network trace to see why the connection is not being established.Try creatting a share on system and try accessing it

Comment: I have tried to see in Event Logger too , my request is not reaching or maybe something is wrong on my configuration

Answer (score 0):

The feature and configuration that our team is directly supporting since it’s still in the public preview is Azure AD authentication for Azure SQL DB V12
see  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/ 
It looks to me that you try to setup your system for ADDS using ADFS and SQL DBs running on VMs.
Is this correct?
If this is the case please contact SQL support organization and ask for help to configure your system.
Thanks,
Mirek